# Scheduled Powershell won't run when triggered, won't stop running when run manually

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to schedule a Powershell script to run from Windows Task scheduler. The script works fine when run manually from a PS window. When I make it the action of a scheduled task, however, two issues arise:

1. When the trigger occurs, the task does not start.
2. When I run the task manually from within Task Scheduler, an empty Powershell console window appears for a few seconds, then disappears. The Task status says "Running," and remains that way until I manually end it.

I have confirmed that the task is set up with correct user permissions.

I have confirmed in Event Viewer that the trigger event has occurred and been logged correctly.

The action for the task is:

> "Start a Program" Program/script: `powershell` Arguments: `-File "C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\script.ps1"`

Here's the relevant parts of my script:

```
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
If (!(Test-NetConnection -ComputerName www.example.com -InformationLevel "Quiet")) {
    #The code in here won't affect basic execution, since during testing this If condition evaluates to False
} Else { 
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("You're good to go!" , "Info" , 3)
    Exit
}
```

I would expect that when I test this task, I should just get the messagebox popping up, then the task should stop running. Neither of these occur, and I really have no idea why.

Comment: Is the task itself hidden? Let's insure PowerShell also shows the window by appending `-WindowStyle Normal` to the task arguments.

Comment: Regarding the trigger, can you check the task history? Also post the trigger details so we have more info. It might be wrong.

Comment: There are many, many previous questions here on SO about how to run PS in Task Scheduler - this is a common error. Add `Start-Transcript` to your script and log what its doing then do some searching here for your resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that "running scripts is disabled on this system."

> about_Execution_Policies https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170
> SecurityError: ParentContainsErrorRecordException | UnauthorizedAccess

The solution was to add `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` to the task arguments.
(There is now a separate issue of a console window appearing on the screen that `-WindowStyle Hidden` doesn't solve, but there's lots of similar documentation for that problem, and I'll post a new question if I can't find a suitable solution).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the failure to start, but I ran into the "failure to stop" issue myself. It turned out that the task had actually stopped, but the Task Scheduler window does not update to reflect that fact, so that it looks like it's still running.

In Task Scheduler, select Task Scheduler Library in the left pane, then click Refresh in the right pane under Actions.